# Kendo Datepicker format not changing

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I've got a Kendo Datepicker which displays as dd/MM/yyyy, which is fair enough. However, I'm wanting to change it to MM/dd/yyyy but whenever I do (by changing format in the below), it either remains at dd/MM/yyyy or becomes blank:

```
<input name="saleDate" id="txt-saleDate" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: saleDate, format: 'MM/dd/yyyy', enabled: $parent.isNewSales }" />
```

Tried changing the format to 'MM/dd/yyyy' (as above) and also 'yyyy/MM/dd' but none of these have worked. Also tried using parseFormats.

Comment: try using this M/d/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Are you sure that `data-bind="kendoDatePicker: {  }"` is the correct syntax? When using that format inside the regular javascript constructor everything works great.

Comment: M/d/yyyy does nothing new - stays as dd/MM/yyyy. May have to try some different syntax as Dekel suggests.

Comment: Are you using knockout?

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index) which has an example in which I can change the format.

Comment: But this is **not** knockout. This is the original kendo lib.

Comment: I don't know - I'm not the original developer.

Comment: I know you are not. If you are using knockout - you should check the knockout library.

Comment: i'm not really sure but hmm never seen kendo used that way, usually data-bind=" value: saleDate" the datepicker should be on role="datepicker". see here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/mvvm, and as for the format in mvvm it would be data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" see here http://dojo.telerik.com/UxusA

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and `format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` code satisfied me. I hope this helps you.

Comment: what {0: XXX}: does? What is the difference betwee {0:format} and format

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txt-saleDate").kendoDatePicker({
    dateInput: true,
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
});
```